# How can I use hash table in OpenCL to look up from big chunk of data?

Tags: opencl, gpu

Is there any way I can use hash table in OpenCL kernel? The data is huge and I have read some posts saying that this might be slow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you getting an error? can you post more info about your problem please?

Comment: I looked at the data types that kernel function arguments can be, and they are all quite primitive like float, int, double. I'm totally new to OpenCL and looking for how to use hash tables. Thanks.